# GET /accounts/login

Tags: python, django, url

I am running a django web server using cherrypy as the server.

I notice I am getting the folloing

```
"GET /accounts/login/?next=/diary/events HTTP/1.1" 500 381
```

I have no idea where this originates. There is no /accounts/login url in any of my html files.
(If I use the django server, I also get this message.

The application is implemented on VPS host.
The message does not appear when I run it locally.

Comment: the url is the default for LOGIN_URL - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url and could be triggered by login_required on your view?

Comment: Also, the return code is 500, i.e. navigating to the login view throws an Internal Server Error. Please have a look at your log file, there should be a traceback showing where the view bugged out.

Comment: Thank you, I will check out what is happening. Yes login_required exists on that view.